# Single dataset for different environments

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

Currently we have different shared connections for different environments. For example: *dev.rds, prod.rds* and so on. So the idea is that when you develop you choose the dev.rds and when you are ready to deploy, you need to switch it to *prod.rds* and deploy. The problem with that is that sometimes we forget to change from *dev* to *prod* that causes that the report goes to production and pointing to *dev* env.

Is there any way to configure different connection strings on different environments and use the same name?

Answer (score 2):

The way we do it...

Each report has a single shared datasource and/or dataset. During developemnt, we deploy to the dev SSR server and the connection will point to the dev box.

For production we deploy the dataset/datasource and then manually update it on the production SSRS server to point to production SQL server.

After this any report that uses that same dataset/datasource name can be deployed to either server and always point to the correct place. We leave the default option of overwriting data sources OFF.

This way you still need to remember to do it but it you do it as you deploy the datasource it's not easy to forget.

We also make sure the production server cannot access the dev server by using a fixed sql login for the datasources that has no access to dev. This way, even if you deploy the datasource and try to point it at the dev server, the report will fail. I find this much better as it's in your face that something is wrong.